# Divide lists and increment every element of list by its depth in Prolog

Tags: list, prolog

I'm trying to increment every element of list by its depth. For example:

```
foo([0, 0, [0]], [1, 1, [2]]) -> true
```

Also, I'd like to do that without any built-in Prolog list predicates. Any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

For divide_half, you need to verify 2 things (which can be done independently): that the lists define some kind of split, and that parts of the split have close enough lengths.

For the second, start by trying to FIND each element, then modify that to track the depth, and finally modify THAT to build up a copy of the list w/ the elements modified (though I don't understand what it means to one-increment something by a number).

Comment: thanks for the lead, i did it that way > i'm going through every element, increment it (if it is not list), if it is list i call the function again,and icrement a variable. but i have problem with lists like [1,[1,1]], because i cant do A is B +1 if B is [1,1] :-/

Answer (score 0):

This definition divides a list without any built-in predicates:

```
halve(List, A, B) :- halve(List, List, A, B).
halve(B, [], [], B).
halve(B, [_], [], B).
halve([H|T], [_,_|T2], [H|A], B) :-
    halve(T, T2, A, B).
```